Is it possible to change suppress exceptions mode by default in symfony 7 debug mode?
TL;DR
Seems like with APP_DEBUG=1 Symfony catches and suppresses kind of exceptions.
Presets.
Installed Symfony 7, --webapp.
Default env, settings.
APP_DEBUG=1
Reproduce
Make ping controller.
Make another dir "src/Dto" and empty class UserDto.php.
Make WRONG NAMESPACE, i.e.
namespace App\Dto\SomeWrong;

class UserDto
{
}

GET localhost/ping
Has 200 with response: symfony version: 7.1.6
Then
Made APP_DEBUG=0 in .env (dev)
Has 500 error
Uncaught Exception: Expected to find class "App\Dto\UserDto" in file 
"/test_project/src/Dto/UserDto.php" while importing services from resource "../src/", 
but it was not found! Check the namespace prefix used with the resource in /test_project/config/services.yaml 
(which is being imported from "/test_project/src/Kernel.php").

I tried to figured it out by debug, but unfortunately I have not such expertise in deep Symfony.
For example, it possible to see exception in browser after request if in index.php make DebugClassLoader::disable().
Inside DebugClassLoader::checkClass() it definitely throws RuntimeException about wrong namespace, it can be viewed by ./bin/console debug:container UserDto
Tags   container.error (message: The autoloader expected class "App\Dto\UserDto" 
to be defined in file "/test_project/vendor/composer/../../src/Dto/UserDto.php". 
The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.)

I tried to make custom ExceptionListener without success.
Seems like symfony catches kind of exceptions and suppresses them.
Now, I found solution for detecting this bug by phpcs + slevomat rules
SlevomatCodingStandard.Files.TypeNameMatchesFileName

But I expect to see ALL errors in debug mode in symfony, however some of them are SUPPRESSED.
It seems quite surprising when APP_DEBUG=0 shows an exception but APP_DEBUG=1 does not, doesn't it?
Is it possible to configure this somehow?

"But I expect to see ALL errors in debug mode in symfony"  - where do you want to "see" them? Why do you set APP_DEBUG=0if you want to debug anything?

> where do you want to "see" them
I expect to view this exception like and another in response when APP_DEBUG=1. In browser for example. But actually place doesn't matter: response, log, stdout -- any can be suitable.

>  Why do you set APP_DEBUG=0
Just for understanding difference. It seems quite surprisingly when APP_DEBUG=0 show exception but APP_DEBUG=1 not, doesn't it?

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it
